# My android phone instal app on it own

Tags: applications

I use Evercoss AT1A and I have problem with my phone.  It installs applications on its own, without my permissions.

Can someone tell me how to fix it?  It doesn't update any applications, it installs new application,  that I don't know and don't want to install.

Comment: Is the device rooted? An app cannot be installed (ignore ADB here) by any other app unless you explicitly choose to, using Package Installer or the app happens to be a system app, such as Google Play service. Either, you've not given us enough details about the auto app installations or the system is infected with a malware.

Comment: Like Firelord I think that's malware behind. But it could also be something else, please see e.g.: [Apps install on their own](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46254/16575) So we need additional details here. // @Firelord remember some malware is able to root devices and thus install everything. Just recently (a week or so ago) a bunch of them got removed from Playstore for that.

Answer (score 0):

Some trojan/viruses do those kind of things, once they got the superuser privilege on your device they will auto install applications from playstore without any intervention from you, try to scan it with Malware bytes or Dr Web Antivirus to check if you are infected. I so far encountered 2 phones behaving same as what you described and found out it is infected. By the way those two phones are never rooted and all applications installed on it all came from google playstore.

Comment: I guess this is what happens to OP's device. Could you include a solution to the issue as well? How did you solve it for the devices you've mentioned? AFAIK if a "rooting trojaner" is involved, flashing a clean ROM is the only answer.