# it downloads apps on its own and does what it wants

Tags: malware

I'm using Android 4.4.2 JK-760 phone and it recently started to download apps on  its own, turn off and on when it wants and throws me out of any app that i try to open. I have no idea what is going on and need help!

Comment: Is your device rooted? When you say it turns itself off and on, do you mean that the device does a full restart? Hope to get your issue sorted.

Comment: Same issue as [Apps install on their own](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/46254/16575)?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like a virus to me. Have you installed any new apps recently? I would suggest trying to uninstall any recently installed apps, and if that doesn't work, you might have to wipe.

As the comment below nicely requested, this has happened to me on an old phone before. Apps that I never installed would appear on my homescreen, etc. It was because of an app that I had sideloaded onto my phone.

Comment: Please cite a credible and technical source that explains: 1) a virus does exist for Android, 2) it can perform actions noted by OP. All those users of MS-Windows, as it  appears to me, believe that if something shady happens in Android then it must be a virus.

Comment: LOL, I'm speaking from experience. It's nice of you to automatically assume that I am one of those "users of MS-Windows", when I actually use all sorts of operating systems. On a side note, that sounds more like something a Apple fanboy, rather than a microsoft fan would say.

Comment: An Apple fanboy and a virus? Somehow a contradiction in terms (they feel much too safe for that). As @Firelord states, there's no virus for Android (and I bet you've just removed that app, and the "virus" was gone – so it wasn't a [virus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_virus) as it didn't replicate). The term "virus" is mostly preferred by those selling the biggest one (called "anti") because it sounds more dangerous. Actually, what you're describing is malware, and most likely a [Trojan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trojan_horse_(computing)).

Comment: What I meant was that it's more typical of an Apple fanboy to automatically assume that everything shady on a non-Apple OS is a virus. I guess I did not mean virus in the strictest definition of the word, and more as just something shady.

Comment: i havent installed anything recently and ive tried to un-install the apps that appear but they re-install themselves later.

Comment: can you give a list of what apps you have installed?